# A text is converting to ASCII or BINARY first?

Tags: email, operating-systems, binary-files, ascii, ascii-art

When we type something in a text file or suppose that I'm sending an email to my friend with an attachment inside the email. In both cases of text file and email. What is happening first? Is that text/attachment converting to ASCII OR BINARY first? When we type something is that computer takes it in binary or ASCII?

Comment: There is no conversion step to ASCII. The text you type _is_ ASCII (or Unicode/UTF-x). ASCII allows the computer to give meaning to the binary and display the right character to you.

Comment: “When we type something is that computer takes it in binary or ASCII?” Everything you type on a computer is binary, it might be using ASCII encoding, but it’s still binary

Comment: So, as per my conclusion, When we type an email, it will first generate the corresponding ASCII. Suppose, the ASCII value is 56. After generating ASCII,the corresponding binary value is created. From here , by using BASE64 A encoding, this will be again converted into 4 bits of 6 segments. That is 2^7. Is this happens?

Comment: What is the role of Base 64 in this image?. Image attached! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTvL5X9WEQmjxIH8KHeYIGHVXjFL04Io/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I don't understand:-( What BASE64 is doing in above image ? Or is BASE64 is an encoding like ASCII? Can we have BASE64 rather than ASCII?

Answer (score 2):

ASCII is an character encoding. Encodings define how text is represented in binary.

The text may be converted **to binary using ASCII**, but most likely a modern encoding such as UTF-8 is used.

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP protocol does not encode the size of the message in the protocol. The end of the message is reached when a single dot `.` is received on a line of its own. So, the protocol doesn't allow transmission of any data that contains a newline, a dot and another newline in sequence.

In practice, it is even more restricted, as several of the old mailer daemons did not handle non-ASCII characters well, so people used *uuencode* to turn binary data into ASCII. The *base64* encoding is a more efficient variant of that, and this is what current mail clients use to prepare binary data that contains non-ASCII characters for transmission.

Comment: So, as per my conclusion, When we type an email, it will first generate the corresponding ASCII. Suppose, the ASCII value is 56. After generating ASCII,the corresponding binary value is created. From here , by using BASE64 A encoding, this will be again converted into 4 bits of 6 segments. That is 2^7. Is this happens?

Comment: @BenDruno, for pure ASCII text, it is sent as is. For binary data, it is converted by base64 encoding. Base64 uses 64 different ASCII characters, so 6 bits of binary data are encoded in each byte transferred.

Comment: You are saying from ASCII,BASE64 is used to convert to binary?

Comment: No, base64 is a method to take arbitrary binary data (values 0-255) and express them as printable ASCII (32-126) to make them safe for transport in an email.

Comment: What is the role of Base 64 in this image?. Image attached! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTvL5X9WEQmjxIH8KHeYIGHVXjFL04Io/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It is possible (but unnecessary) to use base64 with ASCII data, which is what is happening in the image.

Comment: I don't understand:-( What BASE64 is doing in above image ?

Comment: Or is BASE64 is an encoding like ASCII? Can we have BASE64 rather than ASCII?

Comment: Partially yes. BASE64 is a "wrapper" encoding that defines how to transform one representation of data into another, while ASCII defines an interpretation of data, but both give you interpretation rules. The difference is that after base64 decoding, you again have a chunk of data that can be interpreted in different ways (the email headers tell you how).